# Why are some object-literal properties quoted and others not?

Tags: javascript, json, quotes, object-literal

I see this all the time: object literals declared such that some keys are surrounded with quotes and others are not. An example from jQuery 1.4.2:

```
jQuery.props = {
    "for": "htmlFor",
    "class": "className",
    readonly: "readOnly",
    maxlength: "maxLength",
    cellspacing: "cellSpacing",
    rowspan: "rowSpan",
    colspan: "colSpan",
    tabindex: "tabIndex",
    usemap: "useMap",
    frameborder: "frameBorder"
};
```

**What is the significance of wrapping the first two property keys (**`for` and `class`**) with quotes, while leaving the others quote-less? Are there any differences at all?**

I've been poking around the [ECMAScript 5 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm); all I've been able to find is [*Note 6 of Section 15.12.3, emphasis mine*]:

> NOTE 6     An object is rendered as an
>   opening left brace followed by zero or
>   more properties, separated with
>   commas, closed with a right brace. **A
>   property is a quoted String
>   representing the key or property name**,
>   a colon, and then the stringified
>   property value. An array is rendered
>   as an opening left bracket followed by
>   zero or more values, separated with
>   commas, closed with a right bracket.

However, this refers only to the *stringification* of JSON.

Comment: See also [What is the difference between object keys with quotes and without quotes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348478/what-is-the-difference-between-object-keys-with-quotes-and-without-quotes)

Comment: How can this be a duplicate of a question that was asked ten months later?  You guys got it backwards.

Comment: @raven: The answer to the other question is better, and apparently they shouldn’t be merged. My flag was declined. :P

Comment: How is this a duplicate of a newer question ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Those are Javascript reserved words, and (though not really necessary) the syntax of the language requires that they be quoted.

Strictly speaking, pure "JSON" notation requires that *all* of the "key" strings be quoted. Javascript itself however is OK with keys that are valid identifiers (but not reserved words) being unquoted.

Answer (score 6):

There is a reason at this point (two plus years later) to quote object literal properties. If one wants to minify their code using the Closure Compiler they may need to make the properties accessible to other source files. In that case, they will want to avoid having symbols renamed by the compiler. By quoting the property name, the Closure Compiler will not minify (rename) them.

See: [Removal of code you want to keep](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3)

(This applies to at least the ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS setting.)

Answer (score 2):

Javascript language keywords or reserved keywords are always surrounded by quotes in there.

Answer (score 1):

`for` and `class` are language keywords. Your interpreter would throw a SyntaxError when those are unquoted.

See section 7.6.1.1 in the Spec you linked to.

Comment: My interpreter (FF10) doesn't throw anything on `{for:1,class:1,null:1}` and treat them as regular keys.

Comment: See http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-properties for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has a lot of reserved words that are not actually used by the language which I think were reserved for possible future use. `class` is one of these even though Javascript does not actually use classes. Another is `goto` and there's absolutely no chance of that ever being used. The result, however, is that if you want to use these as a json key then it has to be quoted. Strictly speaking you should probably always quote your keys just to avoid the possibility of falling foul of the javascript unused reserved word trap (mind you - I never do).