# What is the difference between object keys with quotes and without quotes?

Tags: javascript

Is there any difference between

```
obj = {'foo': 'bar'}
```

and

```
obj = {foo: 'bar'}
```

I have noticed that you can't use `-` in the key when I don't use the quotes. But does it actually make a difference? If yes, which?

Answer (score 180, accepted):

No, the quotes do not make a difference (unless, as you noted, you want to use a key that’s not a valid JavaScript identifier).

As a side note, the [JSON data exchange format](http://json.org/) *does* require double quotes around identifiers (and does *not* allow single quotes).

Comment: Actually, the quotes _can_ make a difference if you use a numeric literal as a property name. For example, `obj = { 12e34: true };` is not the same as `obj = { '12e34': true };`. The former would require you to access the property through `obj['1.2e+35']`, while for the latter you’d use `obj['12e34']`. [See my answer for more details.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9568622/96656)

Comment: True but it would be brilliant if double quotes were optional given a-z first character +  alpha-numeric and may quite some whitespace fans aka invisible spaces or tabs? great for data not deeply nested.

Comment: @MathiasBynens says that it can make a difference for numeric literal, but I would say that the best way to think about this is that the property that you define/access is always converted to a string. So this is not only about numeric literals, but any property that isn't a string and when converted to a string, produces a different "text value". e.g. `obj[{}]` will try to access the property `'[object Object]'` instead of a property `'{}'` because `({}).toString()` is `'[object Object]'` and not just `{}` with quotes around.

Answer (score 147):

From [***Unquoted property names / object keys in JavaScript***](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-properties), my write-up on the subject:

> Quotes can only be omitted if the property name is a numeric literal or [a valid identifier name](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers).
>
> […]
>
> Bracket notation can safely be used for all property names.
>
> […]
>
> Dot notation can *only* be used when the property name is a valid identifier name.

Note that reserved words are allowed to be used as unquoted property names in ES5. However, for backwards compatibility with ES3, I’d suggest quoting them anyway.

I also made a tool that will tell you if any given property name can be used without quotes and/or with dot notation. Try it at [mothereff.in/js-properties](http://mothereff.in/js-properties).

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 9):

There is no difference here. Just a matter of style. One of the reasons for doing this is being able to use 'super' or 'class' as a key since those are reserved keywords.

Some people might be tempted to pass in a string with whitespace then call o['I can have whitespace'] But I would call that bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

No, not to javascript.  However, some JSON parsers will fail when the quotes around the keys are not present.

Comment: Keys without quotes are invalid in JSON.

Answer (score 1):

There are some situations where they are different. For example, if you are using jQuery, and you are making a list of parameters to pass when calling the jQuery $() command to create an element, quoted words are turned into parameters, and non-quoted words are turned into functions. For example, "size" will set the size attribute of the object, and size (no quotes), will call the size() function on the object. See [jQuery()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), near the bottom:

> While the second argument is convenient, its flexibility can lead to unintended consequences (e.g. $( "`<input>`", {size: "4"} ) calling the .size() method instead of setting the size attribute). The previous code block could thus be written instead as:

Comment: I don't think that example says what you think it says.  The issue you've quoted is because jQuery has a method called size, and the conflict between the method size and the attribute size is resolved by selecting the method.  There are cases in jQuery where passing a _Value_ as a string or another type causes a change in behavior, but never from defining a property with a valid property name in quotes vs not in quotes.