# What's difference between keys with and without quotes in object literal

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between object keys with quotes and without quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348478/what-is-the-difference-between-object-keys-with-quotes-and-without-quotes)

I mostly know JavaScript from using it, but there's something I don't understand yet.

What's the difference between these two object literals:

```
var obj1 = {
   myProp: '123'
};

var obj2 = {
   'myProp': '123'
};
```

Are they just 'synonyms', or is there a subtle difference?

Thanks!

Comment: @EsTeGe: Have you searched for the answer? As Bismark already mentioned, this question has been answered before. -1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the object initializer syntax, keys can be numeric literals, identifiers, or strings.

```
var obj1 = {
    1e9: "123" //valid because it's a numeric literal
}

var obj2 = {
    $_ASd: "123" //Valid because it's a valid identifier I.E. you could make a variable called $_Asd
}

var obj3 = {
    $ hello world: "123" //invalid because it's not an identifier, I.E. you could not make a variable called $ hello world
}

var obj4 = {
    '$ hello world': "123" //valid because it's a valid string
}
```

After that the key is turned into a string regardless of what it was in the syntax, so in the case of `1e9` the key will be a string `"1000000000"`.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing when there isn't an operator inside of it.

```
var obj1 = {
   my+Prop: '123' // illegal
};

var obj2 = {
   'my+Prop': '123' // legal
};
```

Comment: Or a number at the start. The correct way to say it would be "when it's not a valid identifier".