# JS object keys with or without quotes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between object keys with quotes and without quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348478/what-is-the-difference-between-object-keys-with-quotes-and-without-quotes)

Is interest, what is right way, write object keys in quotes or not? that is

```
var obj = {
    "name": "Jhon"
}
```

or

```
var obj = {
    name: "Jhon"
}
```

for example, from php code `echo json_encode(array("a"=>"aaa","b"=>"bbb"));` result is object who has keys with quotes.
But for example see jquery animate, in documentation is keys without quotes, (This is also  JS object format, right?)

```
                $("#someElement").animate({
                    marginLeft: "200px"
                },
                {
                    duration: 1000
                });
```

So, what is more right way?

Comment: Good read about JSON vs object literal: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't confuse JSON object and Javascript object literal. JSON object is basicly just a string and its syntax requires to have proper quotes. However for javascript object quotes around its properties are not necessary. But in some cases you have to use them, e.g:

```
var test = {
    "with spaces": 12
}
```

Comment: O, right I confuse JSOn and JS objects.  As I understood, in any case, better is write keys in quotes, so, thanks.

Comment: No, better to not use quotes. Realy. You only need these extra characters in case if property name is not valid identifier: "with space", "hello-john", "123test", etc.