# Ajax Syntax error

Tags: javascript, ajax

please i need help in my ajax code, i have an error in sending the data in ajax.
it give me an error in data syntax, i tried to change it many time and i did't success-ed

this is my code :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "customer.php",
        data: {content : '"msisdn = '+mob+'"' , type : 'GetCustomer' }, 
        dataType: "json",
                  success:function(data){
          alert(data);        
        },
         error: function(error) { 


                }
        });
```

Comment: There's a lot of quotes and an equal sign in the object, is that what you intended to send ?

Comment: i want to send 
content  : ( msisdn = variable already stored in my code )

Comment: and type = GetCustomer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no syntax error in your data attribute (see http://jsfiddle.net/nwjrf0jy/).

If you view the page wit some debugging tool activated you can see the request to `customer.php` being made. In case of jfiddle it returns a 404 error.

My guess would be, your `customer.php` does not return valid JSON content. This includes setting the response headers to `application/json`.

And be aware that because of your additional double quotes your `$_POST['content']` will be `'"msisdn = 12345"'`. Somehow I don't think you want that.

Comment: yes there is no error in ajax syntax , i had a problem in customer.php and i solve it , thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

May be keys used in data object need to enclosed in quots.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "customer.php",
    data: {'content' : '"msisdn = '+mob+'"' , 'type' : 'GetCustomer' }, 
    dataType: "json",
              success:function(data){
      alert(data);        
    },
     error: function(error) { 


            }
    });
```

Comment: No, not if they do not contain special characters. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12992018/1625955).