# Mongoose + CoffeeScript 'default' property - Getting it to work?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, mongoose

As you know, MongooseJS has a "default" property available. For instance, if I want a Date property on my object, and I want that date to automatically default to the time at which the record is created, I would define it in the schema as:

```
var myObject = mongoose.Schema({
  date: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

Now, the problem with doing this in CoffeeScript is that `default` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript, so the CoffeeScript compiler automatically wraps `default` in double quotes, so this CoffeeScript code:

```
myObject = mongoose.Schema
    date:
        type: Date
        default: Date.now
```

is compiled as:

```
var myObject;
myObject = mongoose.Schema({
    date: {type: Date, "default": Date.now}
});
```

This results in the `default` parameter not working as intended. Perhaps I'm missing something but everything I have tried just is not working. I shouldn't need to manually set the date when saving the record, as the `default` keyword already provides this functionality.

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: Having that key as `"default":` instead of `default:` is just fine and won't stop it from working.  Something else is going on here.

Comment: Can you point me to something explaining this? I've compiled the CoffeeScript to JS and manually removed the double quotes around the `default` property, and it seems to work.

Comment: I actually _add_ those quotes to my `default` keys in Mongoose schemas to keep my editor's JS linter happy, so I know it works.  More generally, here's an [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348478/what-is-the-difference-between-object-keys-with-quotes-and-without-quotes) about keys with quotes vs. without.  There are only a few edge cases where they're different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution to my problem was rather simple, and a rookie mistake: I forgot to specify the Date property to return in myObject.find()...

Answer (score 1):

I have to admit I hate CoffeeScript and the like, but you probably might get around this by doing something like this:

```
var schema = {
   type: Date
};

schema["default"] = Date.now;

myObject = mongoose.Schema(schema);
```

Comment: This seems interesting and it works, but I'm rather inquisitive as to JohnnyK's comment on my question - waiting for further input before I accept an answer.