# What is the difference between these two notations for Javascript objects/associative array?

Tags: javascript, object

What is the difference between this

```
var person = {
    name: "Bob",
    age: "99"
};
```

and this?

```
var person = {
    "name": "Bob",
    "age": "99"
};
```

Or do they mean the same thing?  If they do, what if I want the key to be an object?  How would I specify the object as the key if `name` means `"name"`?

Comment: Object can't be the key. Object can be a value.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo that statement is both vague and misleading. The _string_ `"object"` is a perfectly valid property name.

Comment: exact duplicate of [What is the difference between object keys with quotes and without quotes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348478/what-is-the-difference-between-object-keys-with-quotes-and-without-quotes)

Comment: @MattBall, do I say _string_ `"object"` is not a valid property name? I don't even say `x = {object: "foo"};` is invalid! It is valid but the key `object` of `x` is converted implicitly to _string_ `"object"` and has nothing to do with `object` from global namespace. Misleading? Yes, using keys like `object` or `"object"` is misleading, confusing etc. And don't try to tell me that _string_ is an _object_ too. I know that. The main thing is that whatever the key is, it will be converted to _string_ if it isn't _string_ already. No way to have "object key" with custom methods and attrs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference. Quotes are only necessary if you want to use a string as a property name, but that string is not a valid identifier. Further,

> An object property name can be any valid JavaScript string, or anything that can be converted to a string, including the empty string. However, any property name that is not a valid JavaScript identifier (for example, a property name that has space or dash, or starts with a number) can only be accessed using the square bracket notation.

[(source)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties)

[Object literal syntax is covered in-depth on MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals)

Comment: Another good link I found with helpful explanations. [link](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-properties)

Comment: Indeed. Mathias knows his stuff.

Comment: and on most browsers, quotes are necessary if the property name is a keyword

Comment: @Alnitak keywords are a subset of strings which are not valid identifiers, but it can't hurt to be explicit.

Comment: @MattBall, keywords are not a subset of strings which are not valid identifiers. First of all, `foo bar` is a string and is not a valid identifier and is not a keyword in any programming language I know. Furthermore, term _string_ in programming is a data type or/and class, in some languages equivalent of array of chars. `Keywords` are a subset of `words` or `tokens` - they are called `reserved words` too as they have special meaning in language grammar. But you can't even say that keyword can't be identifier - `this` is a keyword and an identifier as well in javascript.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo I don't see how `foo bar` serves as a counterexample to my statement. By definition, [every keyword/reserved word in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) is not a valid identifier. From that linked page: _"The following are keywords and may not be used as variables, functions, methods, or **object identifiers**"_ (emphasis added)

Comment: @MattBall, I say you are using _string_ term in wrong context.

Answer (score 0):

They are equivalent in this case, but the quoted version allows you to use keys that are not valid JS identifiers. For example, this does not work:

```
{ -test: 42 }
```

while this does:

```
{ "-test": 42 }
```

You cannot specify an object as the key no matter what.

Comment: @akonsu: `console.log(h)` to see what happened. Not what you thought.

Comment: You can specify _anything_ as a key, but it will be converted to a string first.

Comment: it gives this: `Object {[object Object]: 1}`

Comment: @MattBall: I'm not sure if being technically correct is more useful to a beginner than telling them "how it works".

Comment: @akonsu: `console.log("[object Object]")` will print `1`. As you see, the key is not really an object.

Comment: @MattBall: Personally I appreciate that. Beginners usually don't. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

They mean the same thing. Valid keys are identifiers, string literals, or numeric literals. See http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5

You can't yet use objects themselves as keys, but WeakMap objects as proposed for EcmaScript 6 will solve this. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap