# jQuery .animate background color, box shadow, and font color

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm new to jQuery and Javascript. I'm using BitStorms box shadow plugin with this, and before adding the background color and color properties, it was working fine. I'm not sure if there's something wrong with my syntax or what the problem is, but here's the code.

```
$('.menu-btns li a').hover(function() {
$(this).animate({
    boxShadow: "inset 0 0 10px #000", 
    background-color: "#000",
    color: "#efefef"
    }, "fast");
},
function() {
    $(this).animate({
    boxShadow: "0 0 0", 
    background-color: "#fff", 
    color: "#efefef"
    }, "fast");
});
```

As the code is, it's not animating the box shadow anymore, nor the background color or font color.

Comment: JQuery itself can't animate colors. You should use this plugin for color animation: http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/

Comment: The - produces a syntax error

Comment: After adding the plugin, its not only doing the animation for my first "a" property, and its only doing the box shadow. Not only that but its only animating for the mouseenter not mouseleave.

Answer (score 1):

```
{ 
    background-color: "#fff"
}
```

is a syntax error (the console should've told you that). You will have to [quote the property name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4348478) to make it valid:

```
{
    "background-color": "#fff"
}
```

Also notice that for animating colors with jQuery you will need to install an extra plugin.

Comment: See [jQuery animate backgroundColor](http://stackoverflow.com/q/190560/1048572) or [just here](https://www.google.de/search?q=animate+colors+jquery) (Never used one personally)

Comment: @M.Bennett: I don't get what you mean with `(…)`. Array literals (`[…]`) do not have any keys. Object literals (`{…}`) require quotes on keys when they are no valid identifiers.

Comment: @Bergi: I can't delete the comment anymore - you're right. I was a little fixated on JSON.

Comment: @M.Bennett: You can always delete it, you only can't edit it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use camel case

```
backgroundColor
```

For font color animate try to use different colors (now colors are equal).