# Difference Between Two Mongo Queries

Tags: json, mongodb

what is the difference between two mongo queries.

db.test.find({"field" : "Value"})

db.test.find({field : "Value"})

mongo shell accepts both.

Comment: it has nothing to do with mongo, it is how you define your json. have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348478/what-is-the-difference-between-object-keys-with-quotes-and-without-quotes

Comment: Thanks for clearing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the mongo shell there is no actual difference, but in some other language cases it does matter.

The actual case here is presenting what is valid [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), and with myself as a given example, I try to do this in responses on this forum and others as [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is a data format that can easily be "parsed" into native data structures, where alternate "JavaScript" notation may not be translated so easily.

There are certain cases where the quoting is required, as in:

```js
 db.test.find({ "field-value": 1 })
```

or:

```js
 db.test.find({ "field.value": 1 })
```

As the values would otherwise be "invalid JavaScript".

But the real point here is adhering to the [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) form.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, so this is more related to JSON.

Comment: @AdeelAhmad in general then that is the case. But specifically as per additional examples given, you need to "quote" this way even with JavaScript syntax or the syntax itself will be invalid. But the general concept is valid JSON and is a good practice to follow.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference in your example.
The problem happens when your field names contain characters which cannot be a part of an identifier in Javascript (because the query engine is run in a javascript repl/shell)
For example `user-name` because there is a hyphen in it.
Then you would have to query like `db.test.find({"user-name" : "Value"})`

Answer (score 1):

You can understand with example: suppose that you have test collection with two records

{
    '_id': ObjectId("5370a826fc55bb23128b4568"),
    'name': 'nanhe'
}

{
    '_id': ObjectId("5370a75bfc55bb23128b4567"),
    'your name': 'nanhe'
}

> db.test.find({'your name':'nanhe'});

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5370a75bfc55bb23128b4567"), "your name" : "nanhe" }

> db.test.find({your name:'nanhe'});

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier