# node js mongodb remove error "key $lte must not start with '$'"

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```js
    db.collection('session').remove({timestamp:{'$lte':a}},function(err, docs) {
        console.log(err)
        console.log(docs)
    });
```

Version mongodb is 2.6.5, when I make this query from Robomongo visual manager it works normally but from node js it throws error "key $lte must not start with '$'"

Comment: It worked fine when I tried it.  Can you edit your question to show an example doc and the contents of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar issue with some downloaded code- shell worked properly but Node driver failed (there was no other external library like mongoose). My installed MongoDB version was 2.6.6 and the package.json had a mongodb entry as "~1.3.18". With a suggestion from someone, I changed the entry value to "~1.4.31" which resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue....
after deep dive into a bug I found an issue cause

**mongod version mismatches with bson version...**

for more info on version mongod bson version check here

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bson

Answer (score -1):

Remove the quotes around `$lte`. It is not a key, but a directive.

Comment: Actually, it _is_ just a key in a JavaScript object at that point, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: @JohnnyHK: Iirc, it is preprocssed, isn't it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348478/what-is-the-difference-between-object-keys-with-quotes-and-without-quotes