# MongoDB Error: "key $ne must not start with '$'"

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I had hunt with this error: [node js mongodb remove error "key $lte must not start with '$'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624729/node-js-mongodb-remove-error-key-lte-must-not-start-with), but that did not helped me.

I am doing following query

```
coll.remove({ _id : { '$ne' :  SomeId }, blah : blaVal });
```

But that gives the error :

> **key $ne must not start with '$'**

I have started facing this issue, when i migrated mongodb 2.4 to 2.6

My configs are:

```
nodejs : 0.10
mongodb : 2.6.8 (no issues with 2.4.x)
mongodb driver (npm package version) : 2.1.3 (have tried with 1.4.x and 1.3.x, but error is still there, even emptying node_modules and again `npm install`)
```

What should I do to resolve the issue?

Comment: In the examples that I see in [this page](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) they use `$ne` and not `'$ne'`. Not sure if that would change something. Apparently, in the post you are linking to there's already an answer suggesting this.

Answer (score 1):

> Keys in mongo are not allowed in Mongo as they are indicating that
> they are an mongo operator. So if you try to store a Document with a
> key $ne it will not work.

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1884#issuecomment-1112931805