# Any difference between using "" or not for properties in a javascript object?

Tags: javascript

I wonder if there is any difference between using "" or not with JS objects

With "":
`var object = {
   "prop1": 1
   "prop2": 2
   "prop3": 3
}`

vs.

Without "":
`var object = {
   prop1: 1
   prop2: 2
   prop3: 3
}`

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348478/what-is-the-difference-between-object-keys-with-quotes-and-without-quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both would work most of the times.

The main issues with this are:

- To produce valid JSON, you need to use double qoutes (even a single
  quote is techncially not standard).
- Sometimes you would use property names that would require you to use
  qoutes. So for example "my-prop".

Answer (score 1):

No difference from JavaScript point of view. These two declarations are equivalent to each other.

Answer (score 0):

```
var object = { "prop1": 1, "prop2": 2, "prop3": 3 }
```

The above object is a proper JSON.

```
var object = { prop1: 1, prop2: 2, prop3: 3 }
```

This is a simple javascript object.

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira. Both are _simple JavaScript objects_ but the second one is not _JSON._.

Comment: Actually, both objects in your example are simple JavaScript objects, and neither is proper JSON. "JSON is a **text format** that is completely language independent" (see http://json.org/), the proper way to represent your first example would be ```var jsonString = '{ "prop1": 1, "prop2": 2, "prop3": 3 }';```

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira You are wrong, try your so called json [here](http://jsonlint.com/). The moment you enclose it in quotes it becomes a string.

Comment: If you try to parse your "proper JSON" object, you get a SyntaxError: ```JSON.parse({ "prop1": 1, "prop2": 2, "prop3": 3 })```. But if you convert that to a string first, it works as expected: ```JSON.parse('{ "prop1": 1, "prop2": 2, "prop3": 3 }');```

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira You dont parse a JSON which is already a json, you parse a _json string_.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira where did you see me writing _JSON object_? What you have given is a simple string which has valid json inside it thats why we parse it to get the JSON.

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira The link you provided has no relevance here. Also instead of arguing simply try jsonlint.com.