# Looping through javascript object converts keys to string

Tags: javascript

When I loop through an object in Javascript to extract its keys, why do the keys convert to string when they were intended to be integers ?

```
obj = {1:'a', 2:'b'};
arr = [];
for(var key in obj){
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    arr.push(key);
  }
}
```

Now `arr` is `[ "1", "2" ]` instead of `[1, 2]`

Comment: not really your question, but in case you want your object's keys: in more recent versions of JavaScript, this can be done directly with [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: @amenthes I saw that somewhere, however I'm unsure of browser support for this fn

Comment: depends on you userbase, but the "last two" browsers implement it across the board. For questions like this, i like to refer to http://caniuse.com/#search=keys

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's not the loop that is converting the keys; it's the fact that keys **can only be strings**. You cannot have any other type of key. If your key isn't a string, JavaScript will convert it to a string when you use it as a property name.

Consider:

```js
key = {
  toString: function () { return "Blah" }
};

myObject = {}

myObject[key] = "value";

// writes "Blah"
document.write(Object.keys(myObject));
```

Note that if you didn't provide a `toString`, the keys would have been the string `"[object Object]"`.

Comment: Point noted. Though this answer made me think that string keys only matter when using JSON : http://stackoverflow.com/q/4348478/4150760

Answer (score -2):

what meagar says is correct, but if for some reason you want numbers you can convert them prefixing with a plus;

```js
obj = {1:'a', 2:'b'};
arr = [];
for(var key in obj){
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    arr.push(+key);
  }
}

console.log(arr)
```

that said , you maybe interested in looking into  [Object.keys method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: How about parseInt ? (explicit & non-hacky)

Comment: @user4150760 sure , I showed a way to have numbers as that's what OP was asking for ; but the best solution is Object.keys()

Comment: yeah or even shorter with arrow function and array.map:


`const objectKeysAsInt = obj => {const keys = Object.keys(obj); return keys.map(key => parseInt(key))}`

Comment: not even related tot he question.