# Is there any other option to include 'input' element from javascript without using single quotes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
 $('<input class="btn" type="button" value="[[[send]]]" title="" />').insertAfter('#something');
```

When I include this input element from js to html, I am using single quotes('). If you see value attribute `value="[[[send]]]"` I have used brackets for localization. If the translated language contains single quotes(french, italian) I am getting `')'missing error` in script.

EX: `$('<input class="btn" type="button" value="send'vara" title="" />').insertAfter('#something');`

Is there any option to include input element without using single quotes ? or Is there any other representation for single quotes in JS ?

Comment: don't do this? Make the base element, then add the attributes with the `att()` chaining function: `$('<button>').attr({ class: "btn" value: "...", title: "..."}).insertAfter...` etc. Also if you need a button, use a button. input type=button doesn't add anything to a form; its value can't contribute to the form post, it's just "a button", so be semantic about that.

Comment: Have you tried this? - `$("<input class='btn' type='button' value='[[[send]]]' title='' />").insertAfter("#something");`

Comment: @Developer107: If I do this, I will be getting same error in value field if the translated string contains single quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$('<input>', { class:"btn",type:"button",value:"[[[send]]]",title:""})
```

Comment: See portion of link  at _"The name "class" must be quoted in the object since it is a JavaScript reserved word, and "className" cannot be used since it refers to the DOM property, not the attribute."_

Comment: @guest271314 and madalin : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9568622/3702797 "*Note that reserved words are allowed to be used as unquoted property names in **ES5**.*" so even `{var : 'xxx'}` is allowed in ES5+

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.val()` method to set the value:

```
$('<input/>', {class:"btn", type:"button", title:""}).val( "[[[send]]]" )
.insertAfter('#something');
```