# mongodb query syntax : not uniform

Tags: mongodb, nested, quotes

**Edit**: This is **not a javascript** question. This is my observation on the **Mongodb console.** 
I am a newbee to Mongodb, a bit confused about the syntax for query commands.
Some commands require quotes and some do not. Here is an example:

Insert one item:

> ```
> db.users.insert(
> {
>  "name": "Ben Bautista",
>  "contact": "987648711",
>  "address": [
>    {
>      "building": "22 A, Bluemoon Apt",
>      "zipcode": 90211
>   },
>   {
>      "building": "170 A, Crompton Apt",
>      "zipcode": 50910
>   }
> ```
>
> ]
>   } 
>   )

**Query:**
The query for *name* works **with** or **without** quotes.    But the query for nested item *address.building* throws a syntax error when no quotes used. (The third query below throws error). 
Is there any guideline for querying nested items?

```
db.users.find({name:/Ben/}) 
db.users.find({"name":/Ben/}) 
db.users.find({address.building:/Bluemoon/})
db.users.find({"address.building":/Bluemoon/})
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :). As per the linked [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348478/what-is-the-difference-between-object-keys-with-quotes-and-without-quotes), whether quotes are  optional or required depends on whether a key is a valid JavaScript identifier. This is part of JavaScript syntax and not specific to MongoDB: strings including dots or dashes (or starting with numbers) have to be quoted. If in doubt, it's probably easier to be consistent and always use quotes.

Comment: Update: I found an explanation in the Mongodb documentation.: When you use the dotted notation, you must enclose the dotted names in quotes.

Comment: The [`mongo` shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/) is an interactive JavaScript interface to MongoDB, so behaviour such as whether quoting is required is inherited from the JavaScript interpreter.