# How to inclue Jquery TimeEntry plugin with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, requirejs, amd

I am new working with  [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/), I have an old **Asp.net Webform** application that I am trying to apply some **javascript** module loading using [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/). In this app I am using a [jquery](http://jquery.com/) plugin named [Time Entry](http://keith-wood.name/timeEntry.html), but is not working if I use [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/), only works if I added the reference the old way. Here is my [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) configuration and declaration. 
In the aspx file:

```
<script src="../../scripts/require.js"></script>
<script>
    require(["../../app/shared/require.config"],
        function (config) {
            require(["appIncidentTracking/incident-type-init"]);
        });

</script>
```

My **require.config** file is like this:

```
    require.config({
    baseUrl: '../../scripts',
    paths: {
        app: '../../app/utilization-management',
        appIncidentTracking: '../../app/incident-tracking',
        jquery: 'jquery-3.1.1.min',
        jqueryui: 'jquery-ui-1.12.1.min',
        jqueryplugin: '../../js/jquery.plugin.min',
        timeentry:'../../js/jquery.timeentry.min',
        handlebars: 'handlebars.amd.min',
        text: 'text',
        moment: 'moment.min',
        datatable: 'DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min',
        blockUI: 'jquery.blockUI.min',
        shared: '../../app/shared',
        bootstrap: 'bootstrap.min',
        'bootstrap-datepicker': 'bootstrap-datepicker.min',
        'bootstrap-multiselect': '../js/bootstrap-multiselect/bootstrap-multiselect'
    },
    shim: {
        bootstrap: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'bootstrap-multiselect': {
            deps: ['bootstrap']
        },
        timeentry: {
            deps:['jquery', 'jqueryplugin']
        }
    }
});
```

and in my **incident-type-init.js** I only call the plugin:

```
/**
 * Incident Type Init page 
 * @module incident-type-init
 */
define(function (require) {
    var $ = require('jquery'),
        jqueryplugin = require('jqueryplugin'),
        timeentry = require('timeentry'),
        bootstrap = require('bootstrap');

    /**
     * Jquery ready function
     */
    $(function () {
        $('.js-timeentry').timeEntry();
    });
});
```

but when the application runs I got this error:
**$.JQPlugin.createPlugin** is not a function, it is like does not find the **jquery.plugin.js**

I checked the network tab in chrome and both files are loaded, **jquery.plugin.js** and **jquery.timeentry.js**

**UPDATE**: In our application, we are using Asp.net MasterPages, and there we are loading an old [jquery](http://jquery.com/) version, 1.5.1, and I use that MasterPage in my page, but when I check the network tab in chrome, is loading the MasterPage scripts first,then all the [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) stuff.

and the funniest part is that sometimes work, sometimes not.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

The module `jqueryplugin` needs to have jQuery already loaded for it. It is not an AMD module because it does not call `define`. So you need an additional entry in `shim` for it:

```
jqueryplugin: ["jquery"]
```

The above is short for:

```
jqueryplugin: {
    deps: ["jquery"]
}
```

Comment: I did that too, same results, but I think that is only to make sure that jquery is loaded before jqueryplugin kick in, and in my case I am doing that even though I didn't declare the dependency, well that's what I understand in my little experience

Comment: What I describe in my answer **definitely** is a problem in the configuration you show. There may be other things happening but I don't have a crystal ball that allows me to replicate your runtime. The only other issue I see that *could* be a factor (and this is just a guess) is if you load jQuery both in RequireJS and outside RequireJS. It is possible to do this, sometimes accidentally. If you *are* doing this, then you must *absolutely* indicate it in your question. Otherwise, the only thing I can say is "good luck in your future endeavors".

Answer (score -1):

I don't think your code is syntactically correct.

Try this:

**1.** Your `script` should refer to the `require.config` in `data-main`.

```
<script data-main="PATH_TO_CONFIG_FILE" src="../../scripts/require.js"></script>
```

**2.** Quotes are missing in paths of the config file. Instead it should be like this

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '../../scripts',
    paths: {
        "app": '../../app/utilization-management',
        "appIncidentTracking": '../../app/incident-tracking',
        "jquery": 'jquery-3.1.1.min',
        "jqueryui": 'jquery-ui-1.12.1.min',
        "jqueryplugin": '../../js/jquery.plugin.min',
        "timeentry":'../../js/jquery.timeentry.min',
        "handlebars": 'handlebars.amd.min',
        "text": 'text',
        "moment": 'moment.min',
        "datatable": 'DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min',
        "blockUI": 'jquery.blockUI.min',
        "shared": '../../app/shared',
        "bootstrap": 'bootstrap.min',
        "bootstrap-datepicker": 'bootstrap-datepicker.min',
        "bootstrap-multiselect": '../js/bootstrap-multiselect/bootstrap-multiselect'
    },
    shim: {
        "bootstrap": {
            deps: ["jquery"]
        },
        "bootstrap-multiselect": {
            deps: ["bootstrap"]
        },
        "timeentry": {
            deps:["jquery", "jqueryplugin"],
            exports:"timeentry"
        }
    }
});
```

**3.** Since your module has dependencies, list them like this:

```
define(["jqueryplugin","timeentry","bootstrap"],function(jqueryplugin,timeentry,bootstrap) {

    $(function () {
        $('.js-timeentry').timeentry();
    });
});
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Let's go in reverse order. Number 3 is not necessary. The OP is using RequireJS's ["sugar syntax"](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar). Number 2 is not necessary either. This is basic JavaScript: keys in an object literal need quoting only if they are not valid identifiers. [See](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4348478/1906307). Number 1 is also not necessary. It is perfectly possible to load a configuration with nested `require` calls like the OP does.