# Why isn't a bound variable modified?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a problem changing the value of a bound variable in Vue (I am not sure whether this is due to my lack of knowledge of Vue, or of JavaScript in general, probably both).

The initialization of the Vue instance is done via the code below

```
var vm = new Vue({
    delimiters: ['<<', '>>'],
    el: "#index-container",
    data: {
        posts: [],
        tags: {},
    },
    methods: {
        switchAll: function(what) {
            console.log(what)
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.tags))
            _.forEach(this.tags, function (v, k) {
                console.log(k)
                this.tags[k] = false
            })
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.tags))
        }
    },
(...)
```

Further down the script, values of `tags` are set  with a constuction like `Vue.set(vm.tags, tag, true)` to ensure reactivity. They are then used in constrictions such as

```
<div class="tag on" v-for="(content, name) in tags" v-show="tags[name]" v-on:click="tags[name] = false">
```

Clicking on this div **does change** the value of the relevant element of the Object `tags` (initialized previously).

So far everything works as expected.

The problem is in the method `switchAll`. When I use it with a similar `v-on:click()` element (`switchAll(false)` for instance), it gets fired up but the console output is the following:

```
false
{"hello":true,"world":true}
hello
world
{"hello":true,"world":true}
```

My problem is that the last line should be `{"hello":false,"world":false}`.

I tried to use `this.tags[k] = false` and `this.tags.k = false` (though both are [supposed to be equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4348478/903011)) and I believe that the issue I have is that (apologies for the wording, I am new to JS) the keys in this.tags are "bare" in my case, and not "quoted". What my operation does is to add a new key, this time "quoted" (but then `this.tags.k = false` should be fine, as `k` is either `hello` or `world` (without quotes).

I am lost - what is wrong in my code, and why the inline code in the first (working) example of the `div` is fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an expert in lodash, but it seems to be a problem with callback function creating new `this`. There are several ways around this problem, like:

- If you're OK with ES6, use lambda functions - they won't create new `this`:

  `_.forEach(this.tags, (v, k)=>{
      console.log(k)
      this.tags[k] = false
  })`
- It can be useful to hold your `this` inside some method-wide variable:

  `var vm = this;
   _.forEach(vm.tags, (v, k)=>{
      console.log(k)
      vm.tags[k] = false
  })`
- Use vanillaJS object loop:

  `for (var k in this.tags) {
    vm.tags[k] = false
  }`

Comment: Thank you - that was this. I always fall afoul of `this` being redefined (coming from a Python background)