# node.js require quotation marks in object array?

Tags: node.js, express, object

I'm confusing whether quotation marks need or not?

If I will make an object array without quotation marks like this :

```
var list = {
    name : 'robert',
    age : 21
};
```

Can I use quotation marks at key name? I can see some of guys using quotation marks on key name..

```
var list = {
    "name" : 'robert',
    "age" : 21
};
```

This is very important for me even though I learn now javascript just beginner I have to make sure that quotation marks as to where I should put it on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348478/what-is-the-difference-between-object-keys-with-quotes-and-without-quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the ways we can create object array. Suppose your object property name is like **powers.0** then the below statement is not valid. It will through a **syntax error**

```
var test={powers.0:"something"}
```

If our field name contains any special characters like dot, space ..etc we should enclosed it with a quotation mark. so the above statement can rewrite as below.

```
 var test={"powers.0":"something"}
```

Comment: Oh my goodness! Perfect! I got it :) Thank you :)

Comment: @Richard you are welcome

Answer (score 1):

Precisely an object is made up of some key value pairs.
It is always a best practice to define key  with quotes. If you don't do, it won't give you any error until that key is not a reserved key.
 you can see the reserved keys here https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/reserved-keywords.

Comment: Okay, I'll practice to define key with quotes :) Thanks a lot :)