# Can't force object keys to be integer

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, types

```
const obj = {
15: 100
};
for(let key in obj)
    console.log(key, typeof(key), typeof(+key))
```

The result is `15 string number`. I'm trying to iterate over object values and put some of them into Map object but types compatibility seems unable to achieve. Am I doing something wrong here or object keys are always strings?

```
Object.keys(obj)
```

also returns ["15"]

Comment: because that is what they actually are. If you want them to be numbers, than map it to a number. `Object.keys(obj).map(k => +k)`

Comment: Good guess, object keys are strings no matter you denote them with quotes or not. See the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348478/what-is-the-difference-between-object-keys-with-quotes-and-without-quotes

Comment: Even an array's keys are, internally, strings: `console.log(Object.keys([1,2,3,4]));`

Comment: Thanks for guiding me to the topic with explanation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Object keys are always strings. You can see more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors):

> Property names must be strings. This means that non-string objects cannot be used as keys in the object. Any non-string object, including a number, is typecasted into a string via the toString method.

For you to be able to achieve what you want you will need to cast the keys back to integers.