# Distinction between classes (vuejs)

Tags: vue.js

I am reading the VueJS documentation, and I came across this section on Class and Style Bindings.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax

Why is there a distinction between the class ***active*** and class ***text-danger*** since the latter is in single quotation marks?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between object keys with quotes and without quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348478/what-is-the-difference-between-object-keys-with-quotes-and-without-quotes)

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference! The quotation marks just allows you to escape the dash symbol in the variable name