# Passing variable with JavaScript Ajax jQuery to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I searched the advised questions and my code seems to be correct but it

Here is my html code first with the implemented js code

```
<form>
    <input id="inhalt" type="text" name="eingabe">
    <button type="button" id="button" value="bestätigen">Transfer</button>
</form>
<script>
    $('#button').click(function(){
        var variableAjax = $('#inhalt').val();
        console.log(variableAjax);
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "html.php",
            data: {
                variableAjax : variableAjax,
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log("hallo"+data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The PHP site

```
<?php


if(!empty($_POST['variableAjax'])){
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['variableAjax']);
}

var_dump($name);
?>
```

Browser console I can see the entered value I have also implemented the required cdn

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I have also following informations on my browser network

```
304
    GET 
localhost   html.html?eingabe=dfadfads  document    html    Aus Cache   833 B
304
    GET 
ajax.googleapis.com jquery.min.js   script  js  Aus Cache   0 B
200
    GET 
localhost   favicon.ico img x-icon  Aus Cache   30,17 KB
200
    POST    
localhost   html.php
```

On PHP site I get this information

```
Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\YOUTUBE\TEST\html.php on line 8
NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple: What you have to understand is - naming the key properly in quotes.

in javascript:

```
$.ajax({
 type:"POST",
 url: "http://some_base_path/html.php",
 data: {
  "static_key" : variableAjax, //here is the magic
 },
 success: function(response){
  console.log("Raw - "+ response);
 },
 error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
    var msg = '';
    if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
        msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
    } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
        msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
    } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
        msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
    } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
        msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
    } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
        msg = 'Time out error.';
    } else if (exception === 'abort') {
        msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
    } else {
        msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
    }
    console.log(msg);
}
});
```

in PHP:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['static_key'];
?>
```

Hope this solution will help you out to understand

Use :error function instead using try/catch. error function does almost same work.

Note: to know more about **object keys with quotes and without quotes** [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9568622/4345141).

Comment: Sorry Saud but actually there is no magic in that line  .. `variableAjax : variableAjax,` should work as expected

Comment: Hey Sir, thx for ur answer its now working, can i ask u one more question? is it possible to programm something like a try catch in ajax like in c#? if yes how would be the code look like? couldn't find anything in google which is very surprisingly

Comment: I am very puzzled by this solution. Could you explain why this works? Also @proSkill06s did it REALLY solve the problem, or was it something else?

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef at first I thought I understood the solution, but now actually I don't. If this is the solution, I don't know why it is. I wish there was a clearer explaination.

Comment: @RicardoPieper While this answer is accepted that means it solved OP problem somehow .. while I'm sure that `variableAjax : variableAjax` should work fine (I used to use it like this and it works just fine) something like `url : url` in ajax it'll work fine.. But we always don't have any idea what's going on with OP and code behind the seen .. so we're glad the OP problem solved but again the problem isn't in the key static or not .. Finally to be honest I know there is a standard for anything but programmer takes a code which achieve his task ..even with no explanation ;)

Comment: I have updated the code for you, if you have more question please commend it and i will try to ans all of your questions. @-proSkill06s and @Mohamed-Yousef

Answer (score 0):

- When you directly access `html.php` you'll sure get `undefined $name` because you set `$name` inside the if condition
- I think the problem is in the connection between js and php file . For this use the full url in ajax `url` something like.

---

```
 type:"POST",
 url: "http://localhost/YOUTUBE/TEST/html.php"; //<<<< Type here the full url to your `html.php` file
```

<sup>To clarify .. if you've `ajax` in js file which located in `js/js/file.js` and linked it to `index.php` using `<script src="js/js/file.js"></script>` you need to start the ajax url from the `index.php` file</sup>

Also it'll be better to validate the `variableAjax` before you run the ajax

```
if(variableAjax && variableAjax !== ''){
   $.ajax{ .....
```

Comment: on html browser console i get now 404 and php says undefined variableAjax i put the $name variable out of the if scope

Comment: OK @proSkill06s try to remove the if statement and the $name code for now .. and just `echo 'data';`

Comment: @proSkill06s Just to let you know .. We're working now to link the ajax with php ..

Answer (score 0):

Welcome and have a fun with coding!

You're getting error on PHP side means you successfully make a call AJAX with correct file.

$name is decleared and define within if block and hence it's not being aware outside of if block.

You need to declare it before if statement.

```
 $name = '';

    if(!empty($_POST['variableAjax'])){
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['variableAjax']);
    }

    var_dump($name);
```

Now you can access $name after you set.

Rest of the flow is correct otherwise you wouldn't have get an error of undefined $name error.