# JSLint Warning about Ajax data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint

The following is a snippet of my JS:

```
$("#submit-email").click(function () {
    var first_name = $("input[name='first_name']").val();
    var last_name = $("input[name='last_name']").val();
    var telephone_number = $("input[name='telephone_number']").val();
    var email_address = $("input[name='email_address']").val();
    var message = $("textarea[name='message']").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: route_send_email,
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            first_name: first_name,
            last_name: last_name,
            telephone_number: telephone_number,
            email_address: email_address,
            message: message
        },
        success: function () {
            $("input[name='first_name']").val("");
            $("input[name='last_name']").val("");
            $("input[name='telephone_number']").val("");
            $("input[name='email_address']").val("");
            $("input[name='message']").val("");
        }
    });
});
```

JSLint is giving the warning:

> **Unexpected ': first_name'.**
>
> **Unexpected ': last_name'.**

.
.
... up to message.

What exactly is the error? The code works fine, but want to make JSLint happy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with the code is your data property is a JSON Object which the syntax is 

`{
"property": value
}`

JSHint is picking up the fact that you dont have the " surrounding the property names.

your `data` object should become:

```
data: {
     "first_name": first_name,
     "last_name": last_name,
     "telephone_number": telephone_number,
     "email_address": email_address,
     "message": message
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348478/what-is-the-difference-between-object-keys-with-quotes-and-without-quotes/9568622#9568622) Question explains in detail a better answer

Comment: I believe it was the great philosopher, Homer, who once said, "Doh!"

Answer (score 0):

You need to cover your data keys in "inverted commas" sign, like

```
$("#submit-email").click(function () {
    var first_name = $("input[name='first_name']").val();
    var last_name = $("input[name='last_name']").val();
    var telephone_number = $("input[name='telephone_number']").val();
    var email_address = $("input[name='email_address']").val();
    var message = $("textarea[name='message']").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: route_send_email,
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            "first_name": first_name,
            "last_name": last_name,
            "telephone_number": telephone_number,
            "email_address": email_address,
            "message": message
        },
        success: function () {
            $("input[name='first_name']").val("");
            $("input[name='last_name']").val("");
            $("input[name='telephone_number']").val("");
            $("input[name='email_address']").val("");
            $("input[name='message']").val("");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your data object you must have to write the property name in inverted commas 
like:-

```
data: {
"first_name": first_name,
"last_name": last_name
}
```