# Confusion on Javascript Object's dot method

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

In Javascript, all keys in a property are strings, right? 
So, in other word,

this code:

```
var object = {
car: 'tesla'
};
```

and this code are same:

```
var object = {
'car': 'tesla'
};
```

But why is it so that I can access the key `car` using : `object["car"]` but not using this:  `object[car]`

In other words, why do I need to put the key named `car` around quotes if the key named `car` has already been turned into a string?

I read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348478/what-is-the-difference-between-object-keys-with-quotes-and-without-quotes/9568622#9568622) but couldn't manage to get a clear answer on this particular issue. Hope someone helps.

Comment: Presumably, it's a typo since the OP means to compare dot notation with bracket notation.

Comment: You want to know why you have to use quotes in bracket notation and not in dot notation?

Comment: sorry, typo. Fixed it. Please have a look

Comment: Because in bracket notation `car` is a variable `"car"` is a string. `var foo = 'car'; var data = object[foo]`

Comment: Related questions: [What is the difference between object keys with quotes and without quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4348478/215552), [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4968406/215552)

Comment: Why? Because the language specification defines it in that way. According to the specification `car` in  `object[car]` refers to a variable and its value is used for the lookup. And if you want to use the value of a variable as key in an object literal you have to write it that way `{[car]: 'tesla'}`. And what the reason for this has to be asked the person(s) that did that decision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside an [object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer), an [identifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Identifier) is treated as a property name.

The value used in bracket notation [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) is an expression.

If you use an identifier in an expression, it is treated as a variable name.

Since you can use any expression in bracket notation, you can dynamically generate the value:

```
object[function_that_returns_car(argument_from_local_scope)]

object[`string with ${interpolated} value`]

object[i_from_for_loop]
```

… which is what makes bracket notation useful.

Compare to *dot notation* where you *must* use an identifier and that identifier **is** treated as the property name directly:

```
object.car
```

Comment: I lacked the knowledge that identifiers are treated as variable when they are placed inside a property accessor. Thanks for enlightening me.

Will you please have a look at this snap: https://snipboard.io/Tl4Sie.jpg
In the above snap, 12 was treated as a property name inside the bracket notation, directly, whether if I used quotation or not; since 12 is not a valid identifier, correct?

Comment: @slevin — That's bracket notation, not dot notation, and no, `24` isn't an identifier, it is a number literal (which gets converted, implicitly, to the string `"24"` in string context)

Comment: You are right. But since 12 gets converted to "12", implicitly, and then when I use the bracket notation i.e., object["12"], to call the key named 12, doesn't it look something like this: object[" " 
 12" "]? I mean, 12 just got converted to "12." So when you are using an additional quotation, doesn't it look like object[""12""] inside the bracket notation?

Comment: No. It gets converted from the number 12 to the string 12 and everything else is just syntax that only has meaning in *source code*.