# how to use data sent with Ajax POST in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a strange behaviour, I sent data to a PHP page using Post request, my problem is when I try to manipulate this data (echo for exemple) in PHP page I get nothing, but when I make condition on the value I sent the condition is ok.

My JS code

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'admin/page.php',
    data: {
        type: 'search',
        date1:'2021/04/15',
        date2:'2021/04/13'
    },
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);     
    }
});
```

My PHP code

```
$uname = $_POST["type"];
$date1 = $_POST["date1"];
$date2 = $_POST["date2"];


if ($uname=='search') // condition OK 
{   
    echo $date1;
    echo $date2; 
}
```

Comment: What is in `$_POST` when you `var_dump()` it? I wonder whether the difference in how you specify the `type` variable to how you specify the dates is causing an issue. Two of them use equal-signs and the other does not. Why the inconsistency?

Comment: I'm the`data` object that you POST  you should have `date1:'2021/03/03'` not `date=...'`

Comment: @droopsnoot  it was a typing error while I was writing this post, I just corrected it

Comment: @ Tangentially Perpendicular yes it was just  a typing error while I was writing this post ^^'

Comment: How do you test that? Please describe in detail, what you 're doing.

Comment: @marie_dev Problem is that you are using type (keyword) wiithout any quote.Change your data to this - 
  `data: {
        'type': 'search',
        'date1':'2021/04/15',
        'date2':'2021/04/13'
    },`

Comment: @HritikR that’s not it, quotes would only be required, if the property name was not a valid identifier in JavaScript, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4348487/1427878

Comment: thank you guys for your answers, it was a syntaxe error,that I was able to see based on your messages !

Comment: If it's working now, perhaps you could add an answer to show what the problem was, in case it helps anyone else.

Comment: I changed my data to this --> data: {  'type': 'search',    'date1':'2021/04/15',         'date2':'2021/04/13'  } as advised upper, I remplaced = signe by :