# What is the standard or best practice with regards to quotes on JavaScript keys?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, jsx, tsx

I have been going through several questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348478/what-is-the-difference-between-object-keys-with-quotes-and-without-quotes) to see if there is a standard practice/ best practice for whether to put quotes on keys in JavaScript or JSX or TSX. I, however, haven't found anything and would like to know (before building a huge project on bad practices) which is best between:

```
obj = {'foo': 'bar'}
```

and

```
obj = {foo: 'bar'}
```

Or better yet, is there some document I can refer to for this?

Comment: You only need quotes if you're working with keys that are invalid JS identifiers. Keys *are* valid identifiers in the vast majority of cases. You can require quotes throughout the project if you want to, but it will increase the project size by a little bit and will be little more effort to type, especially if you are have many objects.

Comment: The usual practice is to only use quotes on keys when they are required (because the key contains a character that requires the quotes such as a dash).

Comment: Thanks all. Seems like it's unanimous.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

checkout the [Airbnb JavaScript Style Guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript). It has a standard set of guidelines and best practices.

- [3.6](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#objects--quoted-props) Only quote properties that are invalid identifiers. eslint: [`quote-props`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/quote-props.html)

> Why? In general we consider it subjectively easier to read. It improves syntax highlighting, and is also more easily optimized by many JS engines.

```js
// bad
const bad = {
  'foo': 3,
  'bar': 4,
  'data-blah': 5,
};

// good
const good = {
  foo: 3,
  bar: 4,
  'data-blah': 5,
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I think I'll just adopt the Airbnb guide throughout as I have heard so much about it.

Answer (score 2):

Both work and it's up to you what you want to do but my university teacher did tell us not to use quotations so as to make it a bit different from string value hence our whole class adopted as standard practice

```
obj = {foo: 'bar'}
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems like everyone agrees on this standard.

Answer (score 1):

[ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/quote-props) docs have some input on this:

> In many cases, it doesn't matter if you choose to use an identifier instead of a string or vice-versa. Even so, you might decide to enforce a consistent style in your code.

> There are, however, some occasions when you must use quotes:
>
> - If you are using an ECMAScript 3 JavaScript engine (such as IE8) and you want to use a keyword (such as if) as a property name. This restriction was removed in ECMAScript 5.
> - You want to use a non-identifier character in your property name, such as having a property with a space like "one two".

> Another example where quotes do matter is when using numeric literals as property keys:
>
> `var object = { 1e2: 1, 100: 2 };`

IMO it's good to use quotes when needed.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah I'll go ahead and leave out the quotes. Would probably be better for other devs in the future as well.