# Question about Javascript Shorthand object quotes in the key

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm pretty new to javascript and am wondering about quoting the keys in object shorthand

So I am using the OpenLayers js library and many of the object constructors take `{options}` as the argument for setting different variables, callbacks, etc.

In my code I have a bunch of control objects which are used to manipulate the map and what-not

```
    controls = {
        navigation   : new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation({'autoActivate' : false}),
        zoom_out_box : new OpenLayers.Control.ZoomBox({
            alwaysZoom  : true,
            out         : true
        }),
        ...     
    };
```

In some of their examples they use single quotes for the keys and others they won't `{'ascending':false}` or `{visibility: false}`.

I thought that maybe it had to do with reserved words or functions vs variables but I can add functions to my zoom box:

```
controls= {
        zoom_out_box : new OpenLayers.Control.ZoomBox({
            if      : function(e){alert('blah');}
        }),
       zoom_out_box_2 : new OpenLayers.Control.ZoomBox({
            'if'    : function(e){alert('blah');}
        })
};
```

I test it with an `onlclick="controls.zoom_out_box.if(this)"` and it alerts fine and I get no warnings or errors in firebug.

So whats the difference in the quoting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348867/why-are-some-object-literal-properties-quoted-and-others-not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use non-identifiers as keys in a JavaScript object, in which case, the quotes are required:

```
var obj = { 'not-an-identifier': 42 };
```

In the case where an identifier is quoted, it's just a matter of style/preference/convention.

As a side note, non-identifiers must always be accessed using the square-bracket/array-style notation (`obj['not-an-identifier']`), rather than the dot (`.`) notation.

Answer (score 1):

The [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6836332/96656) is incorrect:

> You can use non-identifiers as keys in a JavaScript object, in which case, the quotes are required

The quotes aren’t required if you use a numeric literal as a property name.

From [***Unquoted property names / object keys in JavaScript***](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-properties), my write-up on the subject:

> Quotes can only be omitted if the property name is a numeric literal or [a valid identifier name](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers).
>
> […]
>
> Bracket notation can safely be used for all property names.
>
> […]
>
> Dot notation can *only* be used when the property name is a valid identifier name.

I also made a tool that will tell you if any given property name can be used without quotes and/or with dot notation. Try it at [mothereff.in/js-properties](http://mothereff.in/js-properties).

[image: Screenshot]