# How save multiple params in variable and add to in url?

Tags: javascript, axios

I have many parameters that I would like to save in the `param` variable and add it to the `url`.

How to save this parameter `filter% 5Binprogress% 5D = true` in the variable `param`?.
I did not have  problem with `expand` --> `expand: track`

In tab network return --> `"https://spotify?expand=track&filter%255Binprogress%255D=true"`

should be --> `"https://spotify?expand=track&filter%5Binprogress%5D=true"`

`%255D ---> should be %5D`

```
const param = {
    expand: track,
    'filter%5Binprogress%5D': true  //problem here
}


axios({
    url: "https://spotify?expand=track&filter%5Binprogress%5D=true",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        'Authorization': .....
    },
    param: param
})
```

Comment: `expand` is a valid [identifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Identifier), why *would* it have a problem? This is a very basic JS error, unrelated to React, Axios or even HTTP: invalid identifiers need quoting as object property names.

Comment: Is the record `filter% 5Binprogress% 5D: true` correct?

Comment: No, it's not, that's why you're getting an error. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/4348478/3001761 for explanation.

Comment: wait, bad dupe. Didn't read it correctly...

Comment: I guess https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348478/what-is-the-difference-between-object-keys-with-quotes-and-without-quotes is the correct one. I can't find a question specifically for "what are valid property names". There is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348867/why-are-some-object-literal-properties-quoted-and-others-not) which is close but still a dupe to the previous one.

Comment: People, I mean, is adding such a thing `filter% 5Binprogress% 5D` as a property a is good solution or is it possible to write it differently? Is this done in real applications?

Comment: I don't know why do you want to add this property. So, "is it a good solution" is unclear.

Comment: filters: shows tasks that are in progress

Comment: You seem to have the query parameter in both the URL *and* in the added query params - why? Also if you're getting `%255D` that means the `%` is being encoded to `%25`, so you need to start with an *un*encoded value.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have a special character in object property.

**Try using quotation (single or double)**

```
const param = {
    expand: track,
    "filter%5Binprogress%5D": true
}


axios({
    url: "https://spotify?expand=track&filter%5Binprogress%5D=true",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        'Authorization': .....
    },
    param: param
})
```

Answer (score -2):

Either use quotes or use the bracket notation.

```
const param = {
    expand: track
}

param['filter%5Binprogress%5D'] = true;
```

Or using quotes:

```
const param = {
        expand: track,
        "filter%5Binprogress%5D": true 

    }
```

Comment: `{ 'filter%5Binprogress%5D': true }` is a valid object literal.

Comment: Yes - edited the answer